# Apache Cordova: 'cordova platform add android' failing

Tags: android, cordova

Trying to run the command `cordova platform add android` , I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 24].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

It says that I have not accepted the license agreements for Android Platform 24, which is weird 'cause I have already installed this component and Android SDK Manager kind of forces you to accept the license agreements before install

It looks something is missing, but I don't know what exactly. Any idea? I have already installed all Android SDK platform and tools via SDK Manager